# CygWin suddenly really slow

Tags: bash, performance, cygwin

I've been having trouble with my CygWin terminal for a few days and I can't seem to find what has suddendly made it so darn slow...

Running `$ time for i in {1..10} ; do bash -c "echo Hello" ; done` gives me this:

> real    0m3.084s
>
> user    0m0.106s
>
> sys     0m2.790s

Which seems to be a lot higher than it should be.

I've not installed anything new under CygWin's install path, or made any changes to it.

Has anyone else had any problems similar to this? Or does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Likely a Antivirus effect.

Comment: Started happening for me right after installing Symantec Endpoint Protection

Comment: came to check the solution after 5 years. Things were fine till about couple of weeks back. Suddenly it is extremely slow